# Why Query doesn't work with amp (&) / %26 inside request?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

OK, code returns results normally when there is no ( amp / & / & ) inside query:

```
example1 => BRAHAM BALDWIN AGRICULTURAL COLLEGE
```

is converted and query looks like => BRAHAM+BALDWIN+AGRICULTURAL+COLLEGE

Example 1 => works normally and returns => This school is in Alabama

```
example2 query => BRYANT & STRATTON BUSINESS INSTITUTE - BUFFALO
```

is converted and query looks like => BRYANT+%26+STRATTON+BUSINESS+INSTITUTE+-+BUFFALO

Example 2 => doesn't return anything, I'm quite sure that's because of %26 (amp / &)...

Code in funcs.php:

```
require 'dbconnect.php';

$q = $_GET["q"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bl_zrify WHERE Name = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

  if ($row['State'] == '') {
    $SchoolState = 'Unknown';
  }
  else if ($row['State'] == 'AL') {
    $SchoolState = 'Alabama';
  } 
  else if ($row['State'] == 'AK') {
    $SchoolState = 'Alaska';
  } 
  else if ($row['State'] == 'AZ') {
    $SchoolState = 'Arizona';
  }
  else if ($row['State'] == 'AR') {
    $SchoolState = 'Arkansas';
  }

  print 'This school is in';
  print $SchoolState;
  }
```

PHP code get executed when we type text into =>

```
<input name="SchoolName" type="text" maxlength="50"  size="30"  id="SchoolName" value="" onfocus="showVal(this.value);" />
```

And javascript which we use to pass the string to PHP funcs.php:

```
function showVal(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }



xmlhttp.open("GET","funcs.php?q="+str.replace("&", "%26").replace(/ /g, "+"),true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: First google for "sql injection attack".

Comment: Are you sure that there is a record with that exact name? Maybe you stored the `&` as `&amp;` or `&#38;`.

Comment: keep the string replace portion at separate line, like - var str = str.replace("&", "%26").replace(/ /g, "+"); then use str on your request.

Comment: @mahadeb a) that will make no difference and b) the line you posted would not do anything at all. If you use the `var` keyword for a variable that has already been declared, the value of the variable will not be affected. Eg. `var myVar = 1; var myVar = 2; alert(myVar); // myVar is still 1`

Comment: sorry, I can't agree with you. at your example - myVar will be 2.

Comment: I suggest to keep str replace portion at different line so that he can see the final string before send by debugging with alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code with some slight improvements (in comments).

PHP:

```
require 'dbconnect.php';

// ESCAPE USER INPUT BEFORE PASSING TO SQL!!!
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bl_zrify WHERE Name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["q"])."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  // Switch is better for this type of operation
  switch ($row['State']) {
    case 'AL':
      $SchoolState = 'Alabama';
      break;
    case 'AK':
      $SchoolState = 'Alaska';
      break;
    case 'AR':
      $SchoolState = 'Arkansas';
      break;
    case 'AZ':
      $SchoolState = 'Arizona';
      break;
    default:
      $SchoolState = 'Unknown';
  }

  print "This school is in $SchoolState<br />\n";

}
```

Javascript

```
function showVal(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      if (xmlhttp.status == 200) { // break this into 2 statements so you can handle HTTP errors
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "AJAX Error (HTTP "+xmlhttp.status+")";
      }
    }
  }; // functions declared in this way should be followed by a semi colon, since the function declaration is actually a statement.
  // encodeURIComponent() does all the escaping work for you - it is roughly analogous to PHP's urlencode()
  xmlhttp.open("GET","funcs.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(str),true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

However, I suspect the actual problem here is that you don't actually have an exact match for the entered string in the database. Consider using a `LIKE` clause in your SQL instead of an exact comparison. Also ensure the collation of the `Name` field is case-insensitive.

Comment: Many thanks for taking time and improve my code, it's helpfull a lot and most of all im really thankfull for your time and help. Altough It doesn't work even if I try LIKE clause :S

Comment: @ProDraz How have you re-written your query?

Comment: I've tryed this `$sql = "SELECT * FROM bl_zrify WHERE Name LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["q"])."'";`

Comment: I thought that might be the case... It's probably worth you reading [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like). To sum it up, you need to use the wildcard `%` to make it useful. Say my clause was `Name LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["q"])."%'"` - if I entered 'BR' it would match both 'BRAHAM BALDWIN AGRICULTURAL COLLEGE' and 'BRYANT & STRATTON BUSINESS INSTITUTE - BUFFALO', because they both begin with 'BR'. In short, you probably need to make your query more complicated - and for that, I am not the best person to ask.

Comment: => My problem is that I fetch full name as $q => because that input field have other ajax autocompleter code behind and when you type BR you get that results and select one, when you select one that selected is passed to the funcs.php :)

So im passing full SCHOOL NAME to the query. Not sure where is the catch :S

Comment: That does seem odd that it doesn't work - are you sure your not accidentaly encoding the `&` to an HTML entity of `&amp;` somewhere in the AJAX auto complete?

Comment: If you want you can check AJAX autocompleter code here => [link](http://www.1in1.eu/jquery.autocomplete2.js)

Comment: But as I noticed also that AJAX autocompleter is getting broken aswell, when you try to type in "&"... Not sure why I can't search trough DB using this char :S

Comment: Can you edit the question with the code for your AJAX auto completer? From what your saying, I think the problem probably lies within that, rather than the code currently posted.

Comment: Not sure what I've changed it works NOW. Many thanks to you Dave!